# mysql between not working for midnight time

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the data in the last 1 hour at midnight. I have a record in database which have end time as `23:30`. I am using below query:

```
SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE 
(time(end_time) between  '23:00:00' and '00:00:00' );
```

The above query is not returning the records.

If I change the comparision to '23:00' to '23:59', it works but it doesn't works at midnight.

`end_time` is a datetime field but I am storing only time in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `TIME()` function [returns a string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time), all the 'midnight' values ('00:00:00') are compared with '23:00:00' as *strings*. This actually makes sense, as midnight is usually considered to be a beginning of a new day, not a finish of the previous one.

If you still want to include those values in your filter, just use direct check:

```
WHERE TIME(end_time) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:59:59'
   OR TIME(end_time) = '00:00:00'
```

As a sidenote, it's not quite clear why do you use [DATETIME field type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) to do [TIME type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) job.